# How can I make sure my Javascript animation stay under other stationary elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I want the `#movingItem` to move under the `h1` element. I played with the z-index but the `#movingItem` is always laying on top. What can I do?

My code basically looks like this.

js:

```
$("#movingItem").animate({ 'right': -20})
```

html:

```
<div>
 <p id="movingItem" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1">this moves</p>
 <h1 style="z-index: 2">Stationary element<h1>
<div>
```

`p` has position set to absolute

I wont post the exact css I have because my codebase is fairly large but this is a watered down verson of what I have. like @sm1215 said, adding `position: relative;` to my `p` tag is what I was missing

Comment: Your code doesn't work at all (you should add your CSS).

Comment: You should post your CSS, I want to see how you altered your z-index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track with the z-index, you probably just have to set the z-index of the H1 also. You can probably use position:relative on the H1 since it doesn't seem like that would require any absolute positioning. You can adjust the z-index values as needed if there are other layers you want to introduce later on too.

```
h1{
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}
#movingItem{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:1;
}
```

edit: Might want to double check the display of your p element. It shouldn't be set to absolute, though I think you were probably thinking of the position property instead of display.

Comment: Beaufiful! What I was missing was setting the stationary element's position to relative. Thank you!